# Google Chrome extension for MediaWiki / WikiMedia notifications

Tags: chrome, notification, mediawiki, wikimedia

Not so long ago the official WikiMedia wikis introduced a notification feature.

You'll see a little box to the right of your username at the top of the page when you're logged in. It will turn red when you have notifications.

I'm looking for a very simple Chrome addon that just shows this number in the extension icon area of my browser and goes to the appropriate page when I click on it.

Such notification extensions exist for many apps/sites on many browsers, but I can't seem to find any that do the wiki notifications. MediaWiki does have an API.

Prerequisites:

- Must support wikis running on MediaWiki software
- Must support wikis run by the WikiMedia organization
- Must support the English Wiktionary (the wiki I'm most active on)